# Is there a way to send messages to topic only when received from external system?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have an listener which is listening for UDP packets and after receiving and processing that data want to stream it to a topic (currently Kafka).

I have managed to run a sample program of `Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder` producer.

```
@Bean
public Supplier<PacketDataPojo> data() {
    return () ->  {
        PacketDataPojo pdp = new PacketDataPojo(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        log.info("Current data {}", pdp);
        return pdp;
    };
}
```

`application.properties`

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=data
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.data-out-0.destination=data-stream
```

Now as it is generating data with some scheduled interval, how can I make `Supplier` to stream data after packet processing is completed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `StreamBridge` will do the trick for you - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources
So, you may not need Supplier for your case

Comment: I've tired using `StreamBridge`  but getting error 
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.setSkipOutputConversion(boolean)" because "functionToInvoke" is null`
here is my codebase on github : https://github.com/i-dnyan/spring-cloud-stream.git

Comment: Looks like you're using StreamBridge in PostConstruct. . . Why? That is a quite bit early since not every infrastructure piece is created yet.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I've changed the logic to use StreamBridge via @Service and working fine.